# Squid Cache is not caching anything - TCP_MISS is the result every time, please help me fix the configuration

Tags: cache, squid, memcached

I am trying to use Squid Cache for the first time. My aim – is that for any HTTP response from 192.168.0.2:3001 is cached and served from the cache.

My config is as follows:

```
http_port 3128
 
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
 
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
 
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
 
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
 
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
 
coredump_dir /squid/var/cache/squid
 
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 1024 16 256
 
refresh_pattern -i http:\/\/192.168.0.2:3001\/.* 10080 100% 43200  override-lastmod
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440      20%        10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:             1440      0%          1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0             0%          0
refresh_pattern .                              0              20%        4320
```

The problem I am finding is that each time my client makes a call via the proxy, I see this in the logs:

> 1664219486.836 10098 10.1.1.70 TCP_MISS/200 492 POST http://192.168.0.2:3001/InternalCommunicationServices/message/email -
> HIER_DIRECT/192.168.0.2 application/json

I see the

> ‘TCP_MISS’

The client receives the response from the remote server, but on subsequent calls, it continues to trigger TCP_MISS and I never manage to send a cached response to the client.

I imagine the problem is somewhere in the refresh_pattern lines, but I can't see what it is.

What am I missing from the configuration for my intended use case?

Comment: POST requests aren't cacheable if it doesn't contain `Cache-Control` or `Expires` response header. Have you tried GET requests to the Origin server via Squid? Have you tried dumping the whole response header for the specified request via [`log_mime_hdrs`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/log_mime_hdrs/)?

Comment: Ahhhhhh this makes sense. 

I adapted the server side to return 'Cache-Control:max-age=604800' but the same problem continues? I am yet to try GET requests, I will given time, but for now I cant....